# Is it possible to capture that "Send/Receive" event programmatically using VSTO?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Click event of send and receive ribbon in outlook add-in
any method or event to trigger any code on this event

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Application.Session.SyncObjects` collection to retrieve the very first item (it is "All Accounts"), and use `SyncObject.SyncStart / SyncEnd` events.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject

Comment: I used this already but it works only first time for me 
actually I don't know when to use syncStart / syncEnd in this_addin Startup method

Comment: Please show your code. This is an indication that you are not storing the SyncObject object in a dedicated global (class) variable to prevent it from being Garbage Collected.

Comment: ok let me show u the code

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
            explorer.Session.SyncObjects[1].SyncStart += SyncStart_Event;


            explorer.Session.SyncObjects[1].SyncEnd += SyncEnd_Event;
}

Comment: private void SyncStart_Event()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Start");
            var emailAddress = outlookNameSpace.CurrentUser.Address;
            PostReports.HttpPost(Properties.Settings.Default.suspiciousEmails, "ReporterEmail=" + emailAddress);
        }

        private void SyncEnd_Event()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("End");
           
        }

actually i want to post a method on every time send/receive button got triggered or automatically got called

Comment: As I mentioned before, store the SyncObject object in a dedicated class variable to prevent the GB from destroying it.